# Three real polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Theorem. Let $f,g$ be two real polynomials, and suppose that their Wronskian $W(f,g)=f'g-fg'$ has only real roots. Then on any interval $I\subset\mathbf{R}$ containing no roots of $W$ every non-trivial linear combination
$af+bg$ has at most one root.

I have a [proof of this](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/disconj.pdf) but it does not satisfy me because it cannot be extended to more polynomials. Can a better proof be found?

Conjecture. Let $f,g,h$ be three real polynomials, and suppose that their Wronskian $W(f,g,h)$ has only real roots. Then on any interval $I\subset\mathbf{R}$ containing no roots of $W$, every non-trivial real linear combination
$af+bg+ch$ has at most two roots.

Similar conjecture about any number of polynomials.

Remark. A massive computer testing seems to confirm the conjecture, Zbl 1272.14037, arXiv:1010.0665.

Update 9.12.2023: Steven Karp and Kevin Purbhoo posted a proof of this conjecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.04645

Comment: It seems like the natural conjecture is that, if $af+bg+ch$ has $3$ real roots on $I$ then $W(f,g,h)$ has a root in $I$ (and analogously for more polynomials). In other words, we don't care about the distinction between complex roots and real roots not in $I$. Do you have evidence otherwise?

Comment: Never mind. $W(x^3 - x^2 - x, x^2 - 1, 1) = 6 x^2+2$, so both roots of the Wronskian are imaginary, and $x^3 - x^2 - x$ has real roots at $0$ and $\tfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: I'll describe my first approach, which I now see won't work. Map $I$ to $\mathbb{RP}^2$ by $\phi(t) = (f(t): g(t) : h(t))$. If $af+bg+ch$ has three roots in $I$, that means $\phi(I)$ crosses the line $ax+by+cz=0$ three times. The roots of the Wronskian are precisely the flexes, where the curve $\phi(I)$ changes convexity. My thought was that a planar curve which crosses a line three times must change convexity. True in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ ...

Comment: The example of $W(x^3-x^2-x,x^2-1,1)$ was found by making sketches of rational functions with three real roots and no flexes, and then playing around with graphing software to see that $\tfrac{x^3-x^2-x}{x^2-1}$ matched my sketches.

Comment: I keep waiting for someone in Vail or Aspen to open Ron's Ski-In.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: I think the assumption on the complex roots of $W$ is essential also for $2$ polynomials: for another example: let $I:=[-160,160]$, and consider $f$ and $g$ the $N$-Taylor polynomials in $0$ of $\cos $ and $\sin $, with $N$ large. If $N$ is large enough, $W(f,g)$  has no  roots on $I$, and $f$ has a least $100$ roots in $I$ (and so has any linear combination of $f$ and $g$).

Comment: Here is an idea, which may or may not work, but it doesn't seem to have been proposed yet. I think that, in some sense, $\det(f_i(x_j))$ converges to the Wronskian as all the points $x_j$ collide to a single point, say $x$. This does remind me of the Grace-Walsh-Szego coincidence theorem. Maybe (though I am not sure), such an idea could be used to provide an alternative proof for the $n = 2$ case? I can try to think about this idea tomorrow or soon enough.

Comment: It is true that this determinant converges to the Wronskian when all points collide. But I do not see how to use this. One has to use somehow the fact that ALL zeros of the Wronskian are real (the conjecture is not true without this assumption). And how to use this is not clear.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko. Assume that $n=2$ and that you have $2$ distinct points in $I$, say $z_1$ and $z_2$, at which $\det(f_i(z_j)) = 0$. You want to show that there is some point in $I$ where the Wronskian vanishes, under the assumption on the roots of the Wronskian all being real. Well if you try to apply the GWS concidence theorem to a closed disk in the Riemann sphere containing $I$ and show that there must be a point in that disk where the Wronskian vanishes, then using the assumption that all roots of the Wronskian must be real, one presumably would get that such a root must belong to $I$.

Comment: I am assuming that the intersection of the closed disk with the real "circle" is precisely the interval $I$. I did not think about all the details, but this is my idea.